# Rewrite location to subdomain in nginx

Tags: configuration, nginx, subdomain, url-rewriting, uwsgi

How can I rewrite a subdomain to an application in NGINX?

My configuration is

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
            include        uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9001;
            uwsgi_param    UWSGI_PYHOME PATH;
            uwsgi_param    UWSGI_SCRIPT wsgi;
            uwsgi_param    UWSGI_CHDIR PATH;
    }

    location /app1 {
            include        uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9001;
            uwsgi_param    UWSGI_PYHOME PATH2;
            uwsgi_param    UWSGI_SCRIPT wsgi2;
            uwsgi_param    UWSGI_CHDIR PATH2;
            uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    }
}
```

I want to when access app1.domain.com I got rewrited to domain.com/app1. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to - you can add another server section like:

```
server {
  server_name app1.domain.com;
  location / {
    <uwsgi as before>
  }
}
```

rather than a `location /app1` followed by a redirect.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can either just add the sub-domain to the server name in which case it will just work as the domain but the user will not be redirected and the address bar will show the sub-domain:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com app1.domain.com;

    location / {
            include        uwsgi_params;
            ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a specific server for the sub-domain which redirects to the domain:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name app1.domain.com;
    rewrite ^ http://domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location / {
        include        uwsgi_params;
        ...
    }
}
```